# Add back NAs after removing them

Tags: r

Many operations in R require the removal of NAs from the dataset. In my case, I want to divide a continuous measure into three factors using kmeans:

```
kmeans.2006<-kmeans(na.omit(media.2006), 3)
```

This obviously creates a vector of different length to media.2006. What I want to do is substitute this vector into media.2006 (or a new vector of the same length). I suppose what I would want to do is write a loop something like the following, but telling the counter to skip over any NAs.

```
kmeans.2006<-kmeans(na.omit(media.2006), 3)

n <- length(media.2006)
k <- length(kmeans.2006)

media.factor.2006 <- rep(NA, n)

for(i in 1:n){
 for(j in 1:k){
media.factor[i] <- ifelse(is.na(media.2006[i]) != TRUE, kmeans.2006[j], media.2006[i])
 }
}
```

To be clear, this doesn't work, but I imagine something like this woudl work, if I could tell the j-counter to skip over the case where the i-counter encounters (excuse the pun) an NA. Any ideas?

For reference, I have:

```
> dput(media.2006)
c(NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 385L, 0L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 47L, 20L, NA, 0L, 16L, 116L, 84L, 20L, NA, 0L, 3L, 
28L, 940L, 741L, 177L, 984L, 0L, 27L, 19L, 294L, 79L, 1L, 17L, 
152L, 35L, 87L, 946L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 27L, 10L, 9L, 395L, 25L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 1198L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 19L, 0L, 19L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 25L, 0L, 0L)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easier than you think.

```
media.factor.2006 <- rep(NA, length(media.2006))
media.factor.2006[!is.na(media.2006)] <- kmeans.2006$cluster
```

`is.na` returns a logical vector of `length(media.2006)` and `!` you invert it, so you are telling to replace with kmeans.2006 everything that's not a NA in media.2006.